# NextJS 13: CSS breaks on route change

Tags: css, next.js, styled-components, next.js13

Nextjs CSS breaks on route change on dev and build, gets back to normal after reload. The behavior is different and I'm still investigating it, I have a form that sometimes lacks css completely after route change and shows raw input fields. But most of the time layout breaks . The form is a client-side component.

```
"styled-components": "6.0.0"
"next": "13.4.6"
"react": "18.2.0"
```

```js
// next.config.js
// Load environment variables
require('dotenv').config();

// Validate environment variables
require ('./env.js');

// Next.js configuration
const nextConfig = {
    compiler: {
        styledComponents: true,
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: You don't need `dotenv` when working with Next.js. You simply can add `.env` files in your project root and they will automatically be read and configured. Take a look [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables).

Comment: how do you validate .env then?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the link from the comment? **Read the docs**.